# Gradient for Each Example Using map_fn

Tags: tensorflow

I want to get the gradient of a layer with respect to a parameter matrix for each example. Normally, I would need a Jacobian, but following [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4897#issuecomment-253056458) idea, I decided to use `map_fn` so I could feed forward data in a batch rather than one by one. This gives me a problem I do not understand, unfortunately. With the code

```
get_grads = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.gradients(x, W['1'])[0], softmax_probs)
sess.run(get_grads, feed_dict={x: images[0:100]})
```

I get this error

```
InvalidArgumentError: TensorArray map_21/TensorArray_36@map_21/while/gradients: Could not write to TensorArray index 0 because it has already been read.
```

W['1'] is a variable in the graph. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your issue may be connected with the bug

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7643

One commenter posts a possible fix at the end. You could try that out.

Alternatively, if you what you want is the jacobian, then you can check out this solution:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675#issuecomment-362853672

although it appears that it will not work when nested.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this will work because `x` in this case is a loop variable which TensorFlow does not know how to connect to softmax_probs.